# How to define a reachability timeout on ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, reachability

I use the Reachability class to know if I have an internet connection available. The problem is when wifi is available but not internet, the `- (NetworkStatus) currentReachabilityStatus` method take too much time.

my code:

```
Reachability* reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"];
NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
```

The application "freeze" temporarily on the second line. How to define the maximum time for this waiting ?

Comment: wifi is available but not internet? What it means??

Comment: it's mean that the wifi connexion between the router and the iPad is ok, but there is no internet connection available.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. But more importantly, I don't think you'd want to if you could (you may get false positives). Let Reachability run it's course.

If you look at the Reachability demo project, the notion isn't to invoke `reachabilityWithHostName` and check `currentReachabilityStatus` when you need the Internet. You invoke currentReachabilityStatus at during your app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, set up a notification, and Reachability will tell *you* when the Internet connectivity has changed. I find that subsequent checks to `currentReachabilityStatus` are plenty fast (regardless of connectivity) when I (a) setup reachability at startup; but (b) check for connectivity in a just-in-time manner.

And if you absolutely need to start your processing immediately, then the question is whether you can push that into the background (e.g. `dispatch_async()`). E.g., my app retrieves updates from the server, but because that's happening in the background, neither me nor my user are aware of any delays.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with the same thing but I found a way to specify a timeout. I replaced this method inside the Reachability Class from Apple.

```
- (NetworkStatus)currentReachabilityStatus
{
NSAssert(_reachabilityRef != NULL, @"currentNetworkStatus called with NULL     SCNetworkReachabilityRef");
//NetworkStatus returnValue = NotReachable;
__block SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;

__block BOOL timeOut = NO;
double delayInSeconds = 5.0;

dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){

    timeOut = YES;

});

__block NetworkStatus returnValue = NotReachable;

__block BOOL returned = NO;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    if (SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(_reachabilityRef, &flags))
    {
        if (_alwaysReturnLocalWiFiStatus)
        {
            returnValue = [self localWiFiStatusForFlags:flags];
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue = [self networkStatusForFlags:flags];
        }
    }
    returned = YES;

});

while (!returned && !timeOut) {
    if (!timeOut && !returned){
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.02];
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

return returnValue;
}
```